# What is "magnetic instability"?

Tags: condensed-matter, terminology, superconductivity, stability, ferromagnetism

I saw "magnetic instability" many times in papers about superconductivity, but what is magnetic instability exactly?

like this paper 10.1103/PhysRevB.40.10816 They only mentioned "magnetic instability" in the title.

Comment: maybe link to the papers?

Comment: Just trying to guess from the poor amount of information: maybe it's a tendency of the system to develope some kind of magnetic ordering (like ferromagnetism or antiferromagnetism) for certain values of the physical parameters

Comment: like this paper 10.1103/PhysRevB.40.10816 They only mentioned "magnetic instability" in the title.